# Implement a HierarchicalDataBoundControl for ASP.NET

Tags: c#, asp.net, custom-server-controls

I want to implement a Hierarchical data bound control for ASP.NET.

I used [Implementing IHierarchy Support Into Your Custom Collection](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/custom-controls/IHierarchySupport.aspx) as a basis to create my hierarchical collection. I also created a HierarchicalDataSourceControl for the collection. Everything works: I can bind it to an ASP.NET TreeView and it renders the data correctly.

However, I'm stuck on the HierarchicalDataBoundControl. I found examples, but I am still too new at c# / .Net to understand them. I don't quite understand how to implement the examples:

[Rendering a databound UL menu](http://weblogs.asp.net/dannychen/archive/2005/12/19/433523.aspx)

nor

[HierarchicalDataBoundControl Class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.hierarchicaldataboundcontrol.aspx)

Does anyone have any tips, or better examples of implementing a control like this?

Comment: No one on this forum has any idea about this topic?

Comment: It's not a forum. It's a Q&A site. Read the FAQ: http://stackoverflow.com/faq. It's at the top of each page.

Comment: Yes, I know it isn't a forum, I was actually just adding a comment to see what would happen since it had been a few days, my BAD!

Comment: @Breadtruk: I see you're having issues over on meta. I had one more comment to make, after the "of the mouth" comment, before I forget. To continue the analogy one final step: If you've got that particular malady, consider getting some Pepto.

Comment: @Breadtruk: ok, on to the actual problem. I need an idea of your experience level with controls. What's the most complicated you've created? Any data bound controls at all? Any composite controls? User controls? Done any with designer support?

Comment: @John Saunders: I would say rookie maybe even noob by some peoples standards, just some simple user controls.

Comment: @John Saunders: So does rookie mean I get no help from you since it has been 24 hours?

Comment: I think that if you are "still too new at c# / .Net to understand [the samples]. I don't quite understand how to implement the examples", then you should get up to speed on C# and ASP.Net before taking on this task.

Answer (score 0):

As another `DataBound` controls you have to override `PerformDataBinding` method as follows.

```
protected override void PerformDataBinding()
{
    base.PerformDataBinding();

    if (!IsBoundUsingDataSourceID && this.DataSource == null) return;

    HierarchicalDataSourceView view = this.GetData(string.Empty);
    if (view != null)
    {
        IHierarchicalEnumerable root = view.Select();
    }
}
```

Whereas your control supports `DataSource` and `HierarchialDataSource` control in this case, should check if there is an assigned `DataSource`, get its `DataSourceView` to accomplish data binding. It's practicable through `GetData` method. Then call view's `Select` method to get the root collection.

Afterwards, you have to iterate through root collection that is an object of type `IHierarchialEnumerable`. It has a simple method called `GetHierarchyData` that gives an object which is an item of the collection and returns an associated `IHierarchyData` that describes a node. This methods is there, therefore in most times you don't know the actual type of item. `IHierarchyData` represents some information about a node and its children.

Lastly, you don't need to write a new `DataSource` control. If you are after creating a custom navigation control, it's better to write a new provider for `SiteMapDataSource`.

Answer (score -1):

I faced similar problem and created my own raw html.

```
    private void LoadCategory()
{
    String s = "";
```

// Prepare your dataset       DataSet ds 
// Note That I have Category Table having C_NAME AND PC_NAME coloums, change it as per your column anme
        ds.Relations.Add("rsParentChild", ds.Tables[0].Columns["C_NAME"], ds.Tables[0].Columns["PC_NAME"]);

```
    s = s + "\n   <table>";
    s = s + "\n       <tr>";
    s = s + "\n           <td class='br4'> ";
    s = s + "\n               <table>";
    s = s + "\n                   <tr>";
    s = s + "\n                       <td>";
    s = s + "\n                           <ul id='qm0' class='qmmc'>";
    foreach (DataRow dr in ds.Tables[0].Rows)
    {
        if (dr["PC_NAME"] == DBNull.Value)
        {
            s = s + "\n                                 <li><a class='qmparent' href='#'>" + dr["C_NAME"].ToString() + "</a>";
            s = s + "\n                                 <ul>" + PopulateTree(dr) + "</ul>";
        }
    }

    s = s + "\n                         <li class='qmclear'>&nbsp;</li></ul>";
    s = s + "\n                         <script type='text/javascript'>qm_create(0,true,0,500,'all',false,false,false,false);</script>";
    s = s + "\n                 </td>";
    s = s + "\n             </tr>";
    s = s + "\n         </table>";
    s = s + "\n     </td>";
    s = s + "\n </tr>";
    s = s + "\n </table>";
    Literal1.Text = s;
}
private String PopulateTree(DataRow dr)
{
    String s = "";
    String ss;
    foreach (DataRow row in dr.GetChildRows("rsParentChild"))
    {
        s = s + "                                <li><a href=\"javascript:FetchProducts(1,'" + row["C_NAME"].ToString() + "')\">" + row["C_NAME"].ToString() + "</a>\n";
        ss = PopulateTree(row);
        if (ss != "")
            s = s + "                                <ul>" + ss + "</ul></li>\n\n";
    }
    return s;
}
```

Comment: Thanks, this is what I actually did myself based on some other posts I found. I implemented it in a user control. It really doesn't answer the question though. I still want to work it into a a HierarchicalDataBoundControl correctly